# Send query to 1 big string with | separating each field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query with 3 columns:

```
Market  Unit  Size
10      100   1000
20      200   2000
...
```

Using VBA I need to take the rows of the query and transform it into a string as follows:

```
<row>10|100|1000</row>
<row>20|200|2000</row>
```

I know how to do this by opening the query and looping through the columns & rows adding the pipe + tags as I go.

The problem is this is going to be slow. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you going to do with that big string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **&** operator directly in your SQL instruction to concatenate the columns and the tags you want

For instance

```
SELECT ("<row>" & Market & "|" & Unit & "|" & Size & "</row>") AS Foo
FROM yourtable
```

The **Foo** column will contain what you want.